# Avoiding lock issues when running ogr2ogr concurrently

Tags: python, gdal, ogr

I have a Python script that does some stuff and then updates a big geodatabase with the resulting shapefile. I am running this in parallel so occasionally the ogr2ogr command will fail due to lock issue. I am not surprised since multiple shapefiles could be being written to the same gdb at the same time:

```
ogr2ogr -nln ATL__ZonalStats -a_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:4326 -update -append -f "FileGDB" ATL.gdb ATL__zonalStats.shp

ERROR 1: Failed at writing Row to Table in CreateFeature. (Cannot acquire a lock.)
ERROR 1: Unable to write feature 3128 from layer ATL__zonalStats.
ERROR 1: Terminating translation prematurely after failed translation of layer ATL__zonalStats (use -skipfailures to skip errors)
```

Is there a way I can get around this issue? Like possibly test whether or not a lock cannot be acquired and wait until it can in order to run the ogr2ogr command? I do not know of a way to do this and cannot find an answer (that is not arcpy-related) on here.

Alternatively I could create the big gdb once all the individual output shapefiles are completed but I would really rather not do that.

Comment: probably a crude solution, but maybe you could just put the ogr2ogr command inside a try/ except block within a loop ... so that if it fails it just keeps trying again until it can?

Comment: @Nick this is what i was thinking could be an option but seems really messy. i was kind of hoping ogr/gdal has a method where i can check to see if a lock can be acquired before moving on but it doesnt seem to be the case

Comment: If ogr/gdal has a method to check if a file is locked I'm not aware of it. But regardless wouldn't you still need a similar loop to check repeatedly and finally break out once there is no lock? Doesn't really seem to make things less messy. I'm also not too familiar with how locking work w/ gdbs, might be worth looking into. You may be able to just use os to check if any lock files exist within the gdb directory?

Comment: also i don't know a whole lot about parallel processing or how you are implementing it, but maybe look into using a using a mutex? https://www.8bitavenue.com/python-mutex-example/